# Rider - "Run Last Test" Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: selenium, nunit, keyboard-shortcuts, rider

Recently, I've been working heavily with NUnit. I constantly have to navigate to the name of the function and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Run Test in Debug Mode).

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Run Last Test" so I don't have to navigate to it every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rider, there is an action called "Repeat Previous Run". You can find it on the toolbar in the Unit Test Tool Window:

[image]

It can be found in the main menu:

[image]

And in the Unit Test Quick List:

[image]

If you are not happy with the default shortcut, you can change it in File | Settings | Keymap:

[image]

You can also define a shortcut which will be available only inside the Unit Test Tool Window:

[image]